# How to create a function to subtract two dates?

Tags: sql, function, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a bigdate, a smalldate, i.e., bigdate is greater than smalldate and I want to implement the following code via a function. How do I convert this into a function?

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL (
  CASE
    WHEN TRUNC(datebig - datesmall) = 0
    THEN datebig       - datesmall
    ELSE(
      CASE
        WHEN datebig         - TRUNC (datebig) > (21 / 24)
        THEN TRUNC (datebig) + (21 / 24)
        ELSE datebig
      END -
      CASE
        WHEN datesmall         - TRUNC (datesmall) < (11 / 24)
        THEN TRUNC (datesmall) + (11 / 24)
        ELSE datesmall
      End)
  End , 'DAY')
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are asking is how to create a function this will drop the target function and create your new function.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.YourNewFunction', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.YourNewFunction;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ISOweek (@DATESMALL DATETIME, @DATEBIG DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    -- ENTER FUNCTION
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

And this will call your new function.

```
SELECT dbo.YourNewFunction(GetDate(), GetDate())
```